# CSV parsing returns an empty array

Tags: php, parsing, csv

I have a super simple CSV file ( about 500 lines, 14.5k ) which I need to put into an array which Later I will need to check the ID column against other data set .

The CSV is like so :

```
id,mail,Plan
102,,Plan_Pay
1028,,Plan_Pay
1031,,Plan_Prom
1032,,Plan_Pay
1033,,Plan_Pay
1034,xxxxxx@gmail.com,Plan_Free
1035,xxxxxx@gmail.com,Plan_Free
1036,xxxxxx@gmail.com,Plan_Pay
1079,,Plan_Prom
109,,Plan_Pay
1166,xxxxxx@elid.com,Plan_Prom
12,xxxxxx@gmail.com,Plan_Pay
....
....
(on and on .. about 500 lines)
```

But anyhow I try to parse it , I get an empty array .

I tried with [parsecsv](http://code.google.com/p/parsecsv-for-php/wiki/Examples) lib

```
$csvf =  'id2.csv';

echo $csvf; // debug verify that path exists
$csv = new parseCSV();
$csv->auto($csvf);
print_r($csv->data);// results empty
```

and also with the variant

```
$csv = new parseCSV('id2.csv');
print_r($csv->data);// results empty
```

I also tried ( from php.net ):

```
  if ( !function_exists('fgetcsv') ) echo 'Server too old ... we need to check.';// but it is ok

    function csv_to_array($filename, $delimiter=',')
    {
        if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename)){
         $data = array();
        $data[] = 'no file'; // debug -verify there is file..
        // echo 'no file'; // debug -verify there is file..
        // return FALSE;
    }
        $header = NULL;
        $data = array();
        if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE)
        {
            while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE)
            {
                if(!$header)
                    $header = $row;
                else
                    $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
            }
            fclose($handle);
        }
        return $data;
    }

    $csv = csv_to_array($csvf);
    echo $csvf; // debug verify correct path
    print_r($csv);// results empty
```

I tried all path combinations, relative ( `"id2.csv"` ) , absolute ( `"http://path.to/id2.csv"` ) etc. but it all results the same .

My question is : can there be something wrong with the file itself ? *.CSV is such a simple format , and I have a very small file ( about 500 lines ).
Can it be encoding problem ( it is UTF-8 without bom) . or maybe a server problem ? Or am I just doing it all wrong ?? ( Until now , there were no visible errors anywhere )

Comment: Hate to state the obvious but... do you actually have read access to the file you're trying to open?

Comment: @Filippos Karapetis , I would Assume I have . it is a localhost server on local machine (xampp) . never had such a problem. also, if the file did not exists, I have an ` if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename))` statement - or maybe it is not good enoug ?

Comment: `echo $csvf;` does **not** check if the file/path exists...

Comment: @Shomz - no, it doesn´t , but `if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename))` does ( or should )

Comment: @ObmerkKronen That's much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From PHP DOC](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)

> Note: If PHP is not properly recognizing the line endings when reading files either on or created by a Macintosh computer, enabling the **auto_detect_line_endings** run-time configuration option may help resolve the problem.

If you have set the `auto_detect_line_endings` here is a simpler way to read the csv

```
$csv = new SplFileObject("id2.csv", "r");
$csv->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);
foreach($csv as $row) {
    list($id,$mail,$plan) = $row;
    // You your stuff
}
```

Comment: I don't believe that this is the problem. If that was the problem with the OP's code, he/she would get an array with a single entry, containing a huge blob of text... However, the OP is getting a totally empty array

Comment: @Baba hmmmm.. :-) since you already saved me several times , I tend to believe you :-). But I get this error : `Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'SplFileObject::__construct(id2.csv)` .. ( plus, i do not know if relevant , but it is not a Mac file - it was exported from Open Office on WIN7 )

Comment: @ObmerkKronen are you saying the file is not read at all ? if so can you please verify if your `.csv` is small letters or `.CSV` capital letters ...

Comment: @baba - it is small letters . your script is actually running IMHO - because it takes quit a long time to output the error.. it is not immediate ( circa 45 sec ) . so I assume it does SOMETHING.

Comment: 45 sec ? How big is the file ? do you have xdebug running ?

Comment: No Xdebug here . and yes, about 45 sec.. It might be a memory problem. maybe time to restart the machine . will try and BRB.

Comment: Ok, I am back after restart , and no help. this is the full error meassage now : `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'SplFileObject::__construct(http://localhost/correct/path/to/file/id2.csv) [<a href='splfileobject.--construct'>splfileobject.--construct</a>]: failed to open stream: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond ` . but the echoing stuff in the script (for my path debug) is outputting OK. (server is working..)

Comment: can you change with `is_file` and `is_readable` on the file path before you pass it to the object

Comment: @Baba - I should never have doubted you. ( bad! bad girl!!) I just changed a server to a new version ( have 2 versions on machine to deug old servers) and run your script in an independent file. It works like a charm. It is the server fault. ( php 2.9.x ... ) . Sorry to have wasted yout time.. :-( I still find it strange though that my other attempts did not give any errors..